# Camel for multiple files processing

Tags: apache-camel

I am a new at Camel. I am going to have a file processing with camel but I haven't found a ready solution for my case. I have to process multiple files together in case they exist. These files are uploaded to specific folder with some delays(Example: we have two files A.csv and B.csv, and A.csv is uploaded 10 sec later than B.csv and vice versa). Also if one file is absent more than specific time I need to process only a one file. Could anybody help me with choice a pattern ? As I understand I can use the camel filter to be sure that we already have these two files A.csv and B.csv and only then start processing, but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Aggregator EIP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_camel_development_guide/msgrout-aggregator).

```
from("file:inputFolder")
        .aggregate(constant(true), AggregationStrategies.groupedExchange())
        .completionSize(2) //Wait for two files
        .completionTimeout(60000) //Or process single file, if completionSize was not fulfilled within one minute
            .to("log:do_something") //Here you can access List<Exchange> from message body
```

---

To group messages you can use correlation `Expression`. For your example (group messages by filename prefix before `_`) it could be something like this:

```
private final Expression CORRELATION_EXPRESSION = new Expression() {
    @Override
    public <T> T evaluate(Exchange exchange, Class<T> type) {
        final String fileName = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class);
        final String correlationExpression = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf('_'));
        return exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().convertTo(
                type,
                correlationExpression
        );
    }
};
```

And pass it to `Aggregator`:

```
from("file:inputDirectory")
    .aggregate(CORRELATION_EXPRESSION, AggregationStrategies.groupedExchange())
    ...
```

See this gist for full example https://gist.github.com/bedlaj/a2a56aa9291bced8c0a8edebacaf22b0

Comment: Thank you. Do you know also how to process these two files based on their names ? What I mean: Example there are a lot of files in folder and then a file with such name uploaded UNIQUE_PART_PATTERN_1 I need to have the same what you described above but not only to check if there are 2 files in folder, I have to check if both UNIQUE_PART_PATTERN_1 and UNIQUE_PART_PATTERN_2 exist then start processing, if there is no file with either PATTERN_2 or PATTERN_1 more than specific timeout then i should start processing.

Comment: Are the patterns similar or totally independent from each other?

With `from("file:inputFolder"?fileName="myFileName.txt")` and the usage of an [expression](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html) you can filter.
This does not solve the problem, that *both* files must be given first, in order to trigger the route to start.

Comment: @metters Unique part is the same for only 2 files and difference between these 2 files are PATTERN_1 and PATTERN_2. I'd like to have something like this:
when(filename.conains("PATTERN_1").then checks if there is a file with the same unique name but with different pattern(PATTERN_2), if yes then start process, if no start wait specific timeout. After timeout start process only one file and vice versa with if file contains PATTERN_2

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to let the route be triggered by one of both files?
If the second file is not there yet, check again later (this is configureable with the parameter `delay`) and do nothing.
If both files are available continue.
In order to check whether the second file is there, I would not call `from("file:...")` then, but just reading it with plain java.

Comment: Sounds like you want to customize correlation expression in aggregator. Instead of `constant(true)` pass there implementation of `Expression`, which will return `UNIQUE_PART` based on `CamelFileName` header.

Comment: @Bedla Could you provide an example ?

Comment: @Askeroverflow This `Expression` is correlating messages to groups based on string before first occurence of `_` in file name. You can change its logic to return `UNIQUE_PART` depending on your requirements. See `CORRELATION_EXPRESSION` in this gist
https://gist.github.com/bedlaj/a2a56aa9291bced8c0a8edebacaf22b0

Comment: I have the same situation as "Asker overflow". How to solve?

Comment: Whaaaa??!?!?! so I got Camel to wait for both files but before I can process them Camel ARCHIVED THE FILES. I have no idea why it would do something so insane. I'm just going to wait for one file and write everything else in plain Java.